# How can I add autoupdate in a Qt cross-platform application?

Tags: macos, qt, auto-update, sparkle

I am working on a cross-platform application (Mac and Windows). How can I add auto-update in this application for Mac and Windows, either separately or combined?

By some googling, I came to know about **Sparkle framework** for Mac, but couldn't follow its documentation as it probably explains for XCode project. How can Sparkle framework be used for Qt projects?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use [this](https://bitbucket.org/asgeir/qglitter) for your purposes. Here is it's short description:

```
We needed an autoupdater for our project and decided to emulate Sparkle as closely as
possible but to keep it cross-platform.
Here are the bullet points:
Licensed under the MIT license
Designed for and tested with Qt 4.8
Requires updates to be digitally signed
Periodically checks for updates
Downloads updates to a temporary directory and executes installers (or on mac opens .dmg files), deleting them after install.

Here are some of the things we haven't worked on yet but will once they become more of an issue:
Doesn't have a fancy automated install process. Instead relies on installers and direct user intervention (drag-drop .app bundle on mac).
Doesn't consider updates delivered over TLS to be safe unless they are also signed (unnecessary redundancy)
```